# Вывод таблицы в 3 колонки

Tags: php

Хочу вывести таблицу с данными в 3 колонки - не получается. Прошу помочь.

```
    $namenew = ucwords($namenew);

  echo "<table><tr>"; 
   $x = 1; 

       echo "<td><a target=_blank href='".$name[$i]."'><img src='./img/_share/".$shortname."_1.jpg' width='172px'></a><br/><a target=_blank href='".$name[$i]."'><center>".$namenew."</center></a><br/></td>"; 
       $x++; 
       if ($x % 3 == 0) { echo "</tr><tr>"; } 

   echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: вижу две ссылки.... как вы хотите вывести две ссылки в три колонки?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ссылки-то две, но они внутри одного td. Я цикла не вижу, например.

Comment: Фото и текст. Сейчас вывод осущ. в 1 колонку - нужно в 3. Как?

Comment: делаешь три раза `<td></td><td></td><td></td>` в каждый из которых кладешь то, что ты хочешь

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно так делаю

```
   <?php

 $namenew = ucwords($namenew);
?>
```

```html
<table>
  <?php for($i=0,$size=sizeof($name);$i<$size;$i++):?>
     <tr>
       <td>
          <a target=_blank href="<?=$name[$i]?>">
              <img src="/img/_share/<?=$shortname?>_1.jpg" width="172px"/>
          </a>
       </td>
       <td>
         <a target=_blank href="<?=$name[$i]?>">
             <center><?=$namenew?></center>
         </a>
       </td>
       <td>Из вашего кода вообще непонятно что должно здесь быть</td>
     </tr>
   <?php endfor;?>
</table>
```

Уточните вопрос - уточните задачу и я поправлю ответ, иначе придется отминусовать вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Немного телепатии. Как-то так

```
?>
<table>
     <tr>
         <td><?php echo "содержимое первого столбца"?></td>
         <td><?php echo "содержимое второго столбца"?></td>
         <td><?php echo "содержимое третьего столбца"?></td>
     </tr>
</table>
<?php
```

Comment: Нет. Фото и текст - блоков > 200. Вывод идет в 1 кол. Нужно распределить в 3 кол.

Comment: А css нам всем на что дан?